# How can i use material design feature in eclipse for lower versions of android api i.e 2.1 eclair

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I m already having a code of the app which is in API level 2.1 , I need to change its complete User-interface i want its User-interface I to look and feel like material design 
What should i do ? 
I had imported appcompat but is there any complete guide to help me

Comment: use android design support library. I am not sure it will work for eclair or not.

Answer (score 0):

Google made it possible to also develop Material design apps for eclair using the support library check out these links for how to use the support library

http://android-developers.blogspot.ug/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

**Or**

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/becoming-material-with-android-design-support-library/

Remember to set your `minimumSdkVersion` to `2.1` in the AndroidManifest

Comment: will that work for me ? i want the complete guidance since i am new to android

Comment: @Gurleen It will work and those links i suggested give you the complete guidance.Good luck with Material Design

Comment: how to add design support library and appcompat v7 to my project that is already existing in workspace in eclipse

Comment: @Gurleen which ide are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse juno

Comment: @Gurleen This link will be of help to you http://hmkcode.com/get-your-development-environment-ready-for-android-l-developer-preview/

Comment: @Gurleen If this answer worked for you, please consider accepting it so that it can also help others.

Comment: @ Colns I am getting error  in appcompat  as "Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. android-support-v7-appcompat line 1 Android ADT Problem" and in ERROR LOG I am getting this error "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView"

Comment: @Gurleen Try building the project with the highest API Level you want to support,and you must have the sdk downloaded already, check your `sdk_manager`